# How to merge 2 arrays, 1 being the key and the other being the value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have to arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
    'name' => 'Person Name',
    'surname' => 'Person Surname',
];

$arr2 = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'surname' => 'Doe',
];
```

I want to make the arr1 values become the array keys of arr2:

```
$arr = [
    'Person Name' => 'John',
    'Person Surname' => 'Doe',
];
```

Also note that any of the array can be in any order, e.g. 1st array name then surname and 2nd array is surname then firstname.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I was looking for an easier way without having to loop through the array and create another. here is the result:

```
ksort($arr1);
ksort($arr2);
array_combine(array_values($arr1), array_values(array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `foreach`

```
   $arr3 = [];
   foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
     $arr3[$val] = $arr2[$key];
   }
   print_r($arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this :

```
$new_array = array();
foreach((array) $arr1 as $index=>$key)
{
    $new_array[$key] = $arr2[$index];
}
```

where `$key` is the key of first array and `$arr2[$index]` is the value of second array

Comment: What does `(array) $arr1` brings here ?

Comment: (array) is used to typecast

Comment: I know, but why do you want to use it here as you already know `$arr1` is an array ?